# C# pass parameter to delegate

Tags: c#

Hello I have a little problem with C# syntax...

Right now I'm passing four parameters to a method called `WriteConfig`

```
 var task = fac.StartNew(() => { vault.WriteConfig(fileName, id, queue, DeleteUploadQueue); });
```

`DeleteUploadQueue` is a delegate and gets called with `id` as parameter inside `WriteConfig`. What I want to do is pass `id` to `DeleteUploadQueue` outside instead of inside `WriteConfig` so that I dont have to pass `id` to `WriteConfig`.

`WriteConfig` looks like this:

```
 public void WriteConfig(string fileName, int id, BlockingCollection<byte[]> queue, Action<int> deleteFunc)
```

But I cannot come up with the correct syntax for this.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you change the signature to this:

```
public void WriteConfig(string fileName, BlockingCollection<byte[]> queue, Action deleteFunc)
```

You could write

```
var task = fac.StartNew(() => { vault.WriteConfig(fileName, queue,  ()=> DeleteUploadQueue(id)); });
```

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you want

```
var task = fac.StartNew(() => { vault.WriteConfig(fileName, id, queue,
    () => DeleteUploadQueue(id)); })
```

so if you *also* want to change `WriteConfig` to not take an `int id`, then you'll need to make the `deleteFunc` into `Action` instead of `Action<int>`, so:

```
public void WriteConfig(string fileName, BlockingCollection<byte[]> queue,
    Action deleteFunc)
```

and

```
var task = fac.StartNew(() => { vault.WriteConfig(fileName, queue,
    () => DeleteUploadQueue(id)); })
```

Answer (score 0):

You´re looking from the wrong point. You should provide the arguments for the delegate when you´re *calling* it, not when you´re *defining* it. I suppose this happens within your `WriteConfig`-method:

```
WriteConfig(string fileName, int id, BlockingCollection<byte[]> queue, Action<int> deleteFunc)
{
    /* ... */
    deleteFunc(id) <------- provide your args here
}
```

Providing the parameter to your delegate happens at the line marked with `<-------`. Simply provide the `id`:

```
deleteFunc(id);
```